# Loopback include relations and where

Tags: node.js, relation, loopback

I have two loopback models: `user` and `backendUser`. One (user) is stored with loopback and the other one (backendUser) is stored on a distant mysql database. They have a relation togerther based on a field `user` has (`backendUserId`) corresponding to the `ID` field of `backendUser`

There is a case where I get every `user` with its corresponding `backendUser`. But I would like to get the users depending on some `backendUser` values. Example: I need every `user` where the `backendUser.role` is `4`.

I use this filter to have the expected result:

```
{ include: { relation: "backendUser", scope: { where: { "role" : 4 } } } }
```

My issue is that I get an array of every `user` but I only get related `backendUser` when they have `role` to `4`. The where is only applying on backendUser not on the whole entity.

I don't know if it's clear, but I really need this.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```js
{
    where: {
        role: 4,
        include: {
            relation: "backendUser",
            scope: {
                where: { "role": 4 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
 {
        where: {
          // here specific object of query user
        },
        include: [
          {
            relation: 'backendUser',
            scope: {
              where: {
                role: 4,
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      }
```